# What are good ways to model environment radiance (not irradiance)?

Tags: lighting

I'm trying to compile a list with relevant techniques in game development to model scene radiance.

The (probably obvious) candidates I have so far is:

- Discreet light source objects in the scene (point ligts, directional lights, area lights etc)
- spherical [HDR] bitmap data (mapped to the sphere in various ways. long lat, cube map, oct map etc.)
- spherical harmonics
- halfspherical harmonics

What other relevant techniques are there to model radiance (not irradiance)?

Comment: StackExchange is usually not great at assembling lists. We're better at solving problems. Are you compiling this list to try to find which solution best solves a particular problem in a game you're developing? If so, reframing the question to describe the problem, and in what way the approaches you've tried so far are unsatisfactory, can help focus answers on solutions that will overcome those issues.

Comment: It's for a quality/performance comparison for a scene baking demo. I have implemented the listed versions already and am looking for additional models to implement

Comment: I that case, I'd say you've covered the standard options most relevant to such a benchmark. Do you have any evidence or audience feedback suggesting that you're missing a model that's important to your audience?